# Hibernate Query Language syntax error in query

Tags: jpa, hql

My Hibernate query is:

```
SELECT targets from " + TargetSystem.class.getName()
                + " targets join fetch targets.targetSystemType type"
                + " where type.targetSystemTypeName = '"
                + Constants.Constant_TARGET_SYSTEM_TYPE + "'"
```

And the error I get when I try to execute the query is below

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'TargetSystem targets join fetch targets.targetSystemType ty' at line 1
```

note: targetSystemTypeName is the Java name of the column in the entity and targetSystemType is a foreign key.

Query execution code:

```
Query executeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query,
                TargetSystem.class);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<TargetSystem> targetSystems = executeQuery.getResultList();
```

I can't figure out what is the error

Comment: how do you run your query?

Comment: using Query.getResultList

Comment: ok you use native query.. was that your intention or you want to actually run a HQL query.. not an SQL one?

Comment: I want to run HQL query. before it was native sql i converted that to HQL query but its giving error. as HQL is platform independent so i want to use HQL

Comment: oh I changed the createNativeQuery method to createQuery and it worked. 
after you pointed out that how do you execute query I noticed that i was calling the wrong method.

Comment: Ok great. Glad it worked out for you